# advise on pointing reporting service data sources

Tags: sql-server, sql

It's possible I am unable to resolve this because I have been spoiled in other DEV environments where I had one database server for each reporting server.

I need some advise on how to point a single SQL Server reporting server to multiple database servers.  These databases correspond to DEV, TEST and QA environments.

The way the reporting is currently configured I am unable to toggle between environments gracefully.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle thing would be to create DEV, TEST and PROD folders in Report Manager and then store the data sources in the root of those folders instead of the default "Data Sources" in Home.  I don't think graceful would be a very good description of managing this, but I think it would work.  Another option would be to install 2 more instances of Reporting Service on the same host (would not require additional licenses since on the same host) for each environment.